# Calling SQLBindParameter() in a separate function fails

Tags: c++, sql-server

I wanted to break my code into smaller pieces by moving SQLPrepare() and SQLBindParameter() into a separate function.  (In the real code, the SQL queries are up to 200 lines long.)

1. I passed to the function the Caller's char array that replaces the
   parameter marker.  It would not work.
2. I used an instance variable that I could set in the Caller.  That
   didn't work either.
3. I commented out SQLBindParameter() command in the separate function,
   then copy-and-pasted it into the Caller and supplied it the
   Caller's char array.  It worked fine.
4. I used the instance variable in the Caller's SQLBindParameter()
   command and that worked fine too.

Does anyone know why - apart from my unorthodox coding style - invoking SQLBindParameter() in a separate function doesn't work?

```
MyClass.h
class MyClass
{   char                                        CHRSZ_NameKey[11];
    std::unique_ptr<std::map<int, std::string>> UPTR__NameKeysMap;
    SQLHANDLE                                   HNDL__SqlStatement;

    bool        BuildPreparedStatement( char* );
    bool        ExecutePreparedStatement();
    std::string RetrieveName();
} 


MyClass.cpp
MyClass::MyClass()
:   CHRSZ_NameKey(      "EMPTY"          ),
    HNDL__SqlStatement(  SQL_NULL_HANDLE )
{   UPTR__NameKeysMap = std::unique_ptr<std::map<int, std::string>>( new std::map<int, std::string>() );
}


bool MyClass::BuildPreparedStatement( char* chrsz_NameKey )
{   SQLINTEGER  sqint_NameKeyLengthOrIndicator  = SQL_NTS;
    std::string strng_SqlQuery;

    strng_SqlQuery  = "Select ";
    strng_sqlQuery += "    Name ";
    strng_SqlQuery += "from  Names ";
    strng_SqlQuery += "where NameKey = ?";

    if( SQL_SUCCESS != SQLPrepare( HNDL__SqlStatement, (SQLCHAR*) strng_SqlQuery.c_str(), SQL_NTS ) )
    {   ShowSqlError( SQL_HANDLE_STMT, HNDL__SqlStatement );
        return false;
    }

    std::cout << "MyClass::BuildPreparedStatement()   : chrsz_NameKey            = " <<         chrsz_NameKey << std::endl;
    std::cout << "MyClass::BuildPreparedStatement()   : Address of chrsz_NameKey = " << (void*) chrsz_NameKey << std::endl;
//  std::cout << "MyClass::BuildPreparedStatement()   : CHRSZ_NameKey            = " <<         CHRSZ_NameKey << std::endl;
//  std::cout << "MyClass::BuildPreparedStatement()   : Address of CHRSZ_NameKey = " << (void*) CHRSZ_NameKey << std::endl;

    if( SQL_SUCCESS != SQLBindParameter( HNDL__SqlStatement, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_CHAR, 11, 0, chrsz_NameKey, 0, &sqint_NameKeyLengthOrIndicator ) )
//  if( SQL_SUCCESS != SQLBindParameter( HNDL__SqlStatement, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_CHAR, 11, 0, CHRSZ_NameKey, 0, &sqint_NameKeyLengthOrIndicator ) )
    {   ShowSqlError( SQL_HANDLE_STMT, HNDL__SqlStatement );
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}


bool MyClass::ExecutePreparedStatement()
{   std::string                             strng_Name;
    char                                    chrsz_NameKey[11]               = "empty";
    std::string                             strng_NameKey;
    SQLINTEGER                              sqint_NameKeyLengthOrIndicator  = SQL_NTS;
    std::map<int, std::string>::iterator    iter__NameKeysMap;

    std::cout << "MyClass::ExecutePreparedStatement() : chrsz_NameKey            = " <<         chrsz_NameKey << "    (prior to reading NameKeysMap)" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "MyClass::ExecutePreparedStatement() : Address of chrsz_NameKey = " << (void*) chrsz_NameKey <<    " (prior to reading NameKeysMap)" << std::endl;
//  std::cout << "MyClass::ExecutePreparedStatement() : CHRSZ_NameKey            = " <<         CHRSZ_NameKey << "    (prior to reading NameKeysMap)" << std::endl;
//  std::cout << "MyClass::ExecutePreparedStatement() : Address of CHRSZ_NameKey = " << (void*) CHRSZ_NameKey <<    " (prior to reading NameKeysMap)" << std::endl;

//  <Snip> Connect to SQL Server and allocate HNDL__SqlStatement.

    BuildPreparedStatment( chrsz_NameKey );
//  if( SQL_SUCCESS != SQLBindParameter( HNDL__SqlStatement, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_CHAR, 11, 0, chrsz_NameKey, 0, &sqint_NameKeyLengthOrIndicator ) )
//  if( SQL_SUCCESS != SQLBindParameter( HNDL__SqlStatement, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_CHAR, 11, 0, CHRSZ_NameKey, 0, &sqint_NameKeyLengthOrIndicator ) )
//  {   ShowSqlError( SQL_HANDLE_STMT, HNDL__SqlStatement );
//      return false;
//  }

//  <Snip> Read NameKeys into UPTR__NameKeysMap.    

    iter__NameKeysMap = UPTR__NameKeysMap->begin();
    while( iter__NameKeysMap != UPTR__NameKeysMap->end() )
    {   strng_NameKey = iter__NameKeysMap->second;
        strcpy( chrsz_NameKey, strng_NameKey.c_str() );
//      strcpy( CHRSZ_NameKey, strng_NameKey.c_str() );

        std::cout << "MyClass::ExecutePreparedStatement() : chrsz_NameKey            = " <<         chrsz_NameKey << "    (after    reading NameKeysMap)" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "MyClass::ExecutePreparedStatement() : Address of chrsz_NameKey = " << (void*) chrsz_NameKey <<    " (after    reading NameKeysMap)" << std::endl;
//      std::cout << "MyClass::ExecutePreparedStatement() : CHRSZ_NameKey            = " <<         CHRSZ_NameKey << "    (after    reading NameKeysMap)" << std::endl;
//      std::cout << "MyClass::ExecutePreparedStatement() : Address of CHRSZ_NameKey = " << (void*) CHRSZ_NameKey <<    " (after    reading NameKeysMap)" << std::endl;

        if( SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecute( HNDL__SqlStatement ) )
        {   ShowSqlError( SQL_HANDLE_STMT, HNDL__SqlStatement );
            return false;
        }

        strng_Name  = RetrieveName();

        iter__NameKeysMap++;
    }
}


std::string MyClass::RetrieveName()
{   char        chrsz_Name[257];
    SQLINTEGER  sqint_NameLengthOrIndicator = SQL_NTS;

    if( SQL_SUCCESS == SQLFetch( HNDL__SqlStatement ) )
    {   SQLGetData( HNDL__SqlStatement, 1, SQL_C_CHAR, chrsz_Name, 256, &sqint_NameLengthOrIndicator );
    }
    std::cout << "MyClass::RetrieveName()             : chrsz_Name               = '" << chrsz_Name << "'" << std::endl; 

    return std::string( chrsz_Name );
}
```

The output from passing chrsz_NameKey to BuildPreparedStatement():

```
MyClass::ExecutePreparedStatement() : chrsz_NameKey            = empty    (prior to reading NameKeysMap)
MyClass::ExecutePreparedStatement() : Address of chrsz_NameKey = 0x22fd09 (prior to reading NameKeysMap)
MyClass::BuildPreparedStatement()   : chrsz_NameKey            = empty
MyClass::BuildPreparedStatement()   : Address of chrsz_NameKey = 0x22fd09
MyClass::ExecutePreparedStatement() : chrsz_NameKey            = BB-62    (after    reading NameKeysMap)
MyClass::ExecutePreparedStatement() : Address of chrsz_NameKey = 0x22fd09 (after    reading NameKeysMap)
MyClass::RetrieveName()             : chrsz_Name               = ''
```

Don't know why that fails.

The output from commenting out chrsz_NameKey and un-commenting the instance variable CHRSZ_NameKey:

```
MyClass::ExecutePreparedStatement() : CHRSZ_NameKey            = EMPTY    (prior to reading NameKeysMap)
MyClass::ExecutePreparedStatement() : Address of CHRSZ_NameKey = 0x818a18 (prior to reading NameKeysMap)
MyClass::BuildPreparedStatement()   : CHRSZ_NameKey            = EMPTY
MyClass::BuildPreparedStatement()   : Address of CHRSZ_NameKey = 0x818a18
MyClass::ExecutePreparedStatement() : CHRSZ_NameKey            = BB-62    (after    reading NameKeysMap)
MyClass::ExecutePreparedStatement() : Address of CHRSZ_NameKey = 0x818a18 (after    reading NameKeysMap)
MyClass::RetrieveName()             : chrsz_Name               = ''
```

Really don't know why THAT fails.

The output from commenting out SQLBindParameter() in BuildPreparedStatement() and running SQLBindParameter() in ExecutePreparedStatement() instead, with chrsz_NameKey:

```
MyClass::ExecutePreparedStatement() : chrsz_NameKey            = empty    (prior to reading NameKeysMap)
MyClass::ExecutePreparedStatement() : Address of chrsz_NameKey = 0x22fd09 (prior to reading NameKeysMap)
MyClass::ExecutePreparedStatement() : chrsz_NameKey            = BB-62    (after    reading NameKeysMap)
MyClass::ExecutePreparedStatement() : Address of chrsz_NameKey = 0x22fd09 (after    reading NameKeysMap)
MyClass::RetrieveName()             : chrsz_Name               = 'USS New Jersey'
```

Success!

The output from commenting out SQLBindParameter() in BuildPreparedStatement() and running SQLBindParameter() in ExecutePreparedStatement() instead, with CHRSZ_NameKey:

```
MyClass::ExecutePreparedStatement() : CHRSZ_NameKey            = EMPTY    (prior to reading NameKeysMap)
MyClass::ExecutePreparedStatement() : Address of CHRSZ_NameKey = 0x818a18 (prior to reading NameKeysMap)
MyClass::ExecutePreparedStatement() : CHRSZ_NameKey            = BB-62    (after    reading NameKeysMap)
MyClass::ExecutePreparedStatement() : Address of CHRSZ_NameKey = 0x818a18 (after    reading NameKeysMap)
MyClass::RetrieveName()             : chrsz_Name               = 'USS New Jersey'
```

Success again.

For extra credit, I changed the function signature to:

```
bool        BuildPreparedStatement( char (&chrsz_NameKey)[11] );
```

and re-tried my initial setup of passing chrsz_NameKey.  I got the same exact failure.

How am I mis-using SQLBindParameter()?

Comment: It looks like you are passing `0` as the value of the next-to-last parameter (`BufferLength`) in the call to [`SQLBindParameter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlbindparameter-function)().  According to the docs, this should be the length of the buffer provided, if I understand correctly.

Comment: @Phil [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlbindparameter-function), Microsoft  suggests that BufferLength is required, but maybe for output parameters only (I can't tell).  But in their examples lower on the page, they set it to 0 and 0 works for me outside the separate function.  I went ahead and tried ColumnSize+1 (including the zero-termination byte) inside the separate function; it still failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well reader, you were right: it's a variable going out of scope.

In function

```
bool MyClass::BuildPreparedStatement( char* chrsz_NameKey )
{   SQLINTEGER  sqint_NameKeyLengthOrIndicator  = SQL_NTS;
    ...
    if( SQL_SUCCESS != SQLBindParameter( HNDL__SqlStatement, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_CHAR, 11, 0, chrsz_NameKey, 0, &sqint_NameKeyLengthOrIndicator ) )
    ...
```

the local variable sqint_NameKeyLengthOrIndicator is the culprit.  I thought, because it simply tells SQLBindParameter() that chrsz_NameKey is a Null-Terminated String, that SQLBindParameter() had everything it needed to execute.  Apparently not.

That variable must be in scope when SQLExecute() is executed.  So, changing MyClass::BuildPreparedStatement to receive the variable instead

```
bool MyClass::BuildPreparedStatement(char* chrsz_NameKey, SQLINTEGER& sqint_NameKeyLengthOrIndicator )
{ //SQLINTEGER  sqint_NameKeyLengthOrIndicator  = SQL_NTS;
    ...
    if( SQL_SUCCESS != SQLBindParameter( HNDL__SqlStatement, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_CHAR, 11, 0, chrsz_NameKey, 0, &sqint_NameKeyLengthOrIndicator ) )
    ...
```

and changing the caller to pass the variable

```
bool MyClass::ExecutePreparedStatement()
{   SQLINTEGER  sqint_NameKeyLengthOrIndicator  = SQL_NTS;
    ...
    BuildPreparedStatment( chrsz_NameKey, sqint_NameKeyLengthOrIndicator );
    ...
    if( SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecute( HNDL__SqlStatement ) )
    ...
```

allowed SQLExecute() to work properly.

It seems, in the link I posted for @Phil, that Microsoft really meant it when they said:

> The StrLen_or_IndPtr argument points to a buffer that, **when SQLExecute
>   or SQLExecDirect is called**, contains one of the following.
>
> - SQL_NTS. The parameter value is a null-terminated string.